# Running Python Trainer script in Parallel

Tags: python, linux, bash, python-3.x, terminal

I have a `python3` trainer command which takes in input the

- trainer.py script fileName
- Date
- Input data file
- Output Parameter file

I want to invoke this command for 10 (incremental i.e. `+1`) dates, resulting in 10 output files. The other 2 input file are the same for all the 10 commands. I wanted to know how I can invoke these commands in parallel, across 10 threads (Linux).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Option 1: use in [`parallel`](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/) tool.

> GNU parallel is a shell tool for executing jobs in parallel using one or more computers. A job can be a single command or a small script that has to be run for each of the lines in the input. The typical input is a list of files, a list of hosts, a list of users, a list of URLs, or a list of tables. A job can also be a command that reads from a pipe. GNU parallel can then split the input and pipe it into commands in parallel.

Option 2: manage jobs manually 
To run a job in background just append `&` in the end of command.

**Useful commands:**

```
jobs -r              # list of running
kill -SIGSTOP %N     # suspend job N
kill -SIGCONT %N     # resume job N
```

**Example:**

```
$ sleep 30 & # <- run in background
$ sleep 60 & # <- run in background
$ sleep 60 & # <- run in background

# list of running jobs
$ jobs -r
[1]   Running                 sleep 30 &
[2]-  Running                 sleep 60 &
[3]+  Running                 sleep 40 &

# kill job [3]
$ kill %3

# list of jobs
$ jobs
[1]   Running                 sleep 30 &
[2]-  Running                 sleep 60 &
[3]+  Terminated              sleep 40
```

Comment: Will these jobs be executing in parallel or simply sequentially?

Comment: @Sanchay: in parallel

Comment: GNU parallel tool proved to be super useful. Thanks!